# Local store not working in Internet Explorer - Ext JS

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-9, store

I have a local store here that I put into my application. It works great in Firefox but when I launch it in Internet Explorer(9), the entire app crashes. Any idea?

Here's the code:

```
var filters_2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { //temp store
    fields: ['field1'],
    data : [
        { field1: 'Filter 1' },
        { field1: 'Filter 2' },
        { field1: 'Filter 3' }
    ]
});
```

(The purpose of this store is to load the fields into a combobox elsewhere in my app)

Is there a require or something to that nature that I am missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding field1 in quotes in data

```
var filters_2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { //temp store
fields: ['field1'],
data : [
    { 'field1': 'Filter 1' },
    { 'field1': 'Filter 2' },
    { 'field1': 'Filter 3' }
]
```

});

Comment: This is probably what it is now that I think about it.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work in IE once again. My error is: ext-debug.js, line 4101 character 13

Comment: I solved it by giving my filter an id, and calling it from my button controller. (store: 'filterID')

Comment: I also had to put the store into my launch function. Something doesn't seem right about this...

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a model for your store, sometimes extjs doesn't handle the 'fields' configuration option very well as it is only there for backwards compatability with Extjs 3.X code that has been updated to work with 4.X.

```
Ext.define("FilterModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "field1", type: "string"}
    ]
});

var filters_2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { //temp store
    model: "FilterModel",
    data : [
        { field1: 'Filter 1' },
        { field2: 'Filter 2' },
        { field3: 'Filter 3' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I tried this also, but in IE all I get is error: ext-debug.js, line 4101 character 13